# Django claas Admin auto-populate user field

Tags: python, django, forms, admin, auto-populate

I am trying to populate the field 'owner' in the my NoteForm. I read in documentation that I need to use the Admin for that.But i still get this error : note_note.owner_id may not be NULL. Need help.
Code:
forms.py:

```
class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Note    
    fields = ('title','body')
```

models.py:

```
class Note(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    cr_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False)

class NoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
       form.owner = request.user
       form.save()
```

views.py:

```
def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = NoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return HttpResponceRedirect('/notes/all')


    else:
        form = NoteForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('create_note.html', args)
```

i also tried to write the class NoteAdmin in admin.py , just in case. Same error.What i am doing wrong? I am just following the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save `Note` without `owner` field and the error said it. Try like:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.owner = request.user
    obj.save()
```

The other way is to set `null=True` for the `owner` field if you can write data without owners.

Comment: No still same error :(  . No i need this so i can filter notes for each user. Cause i cant find any other way in django to have separate data for users.

Comment: What does it means 'for start'? When you create an object via `create` function you should define `owner` of the field before you save the data in model. Otherwise you will get errors as you got.

Comment: sr just forget the last comment. What exactly do you need ? other info ? Consider that the Note was created fine before i add the owner field. The problem is that i doesn't get the user_id or something.I also tried this https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookNewformsAdminAndUser . And i put all the admin classes in admin.py like i should have had. I don't thing there is an issue with the urls.

Comment: You are trying to save `Note` entry via admin?

Comment: This the only way to auto-pupulate this  field ModelAdmin.Here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/  ModelAdmin methods. Is there any other way? what i am doing wrong?